# Как включить приложение после перезагрузки или зарядки на Api 27+?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcast-receiver

Приложение должно включатся после рестарта телефона и при подключении зарядки, я сделал это так:

manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ChargingReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


<receiver
     android:name=".RestartReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action
            android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
            tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
         <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

RestartReceiver

```
class RestartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent!!.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context!!.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

ChargingReceiver

```
class ChargingReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Все работает до Api27+. Почитал что на Api27+ нужно использовать JobScheduler, но не могу найти информацию по конкретно моей задаче, это вообще можно сделать на 27+? Если да подскажите пожалуйста как.

Comment: вы на каком устройстве тестируете? XIAOMI ?

Comment: @Style-7 На эмуляторах, и мейзу

Comment: а разрешение есть android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: @Style-7 Да,конечно

Comment: у меня работает, добавьте  <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/> и поставьте Log в onReceive для проверки

Comment: @Style-7 Да у меня тоже работает, но до api27+

Comment: у меня работает везде

Answer (score 0):

Начиная c версии 8 (api 26) согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) броадкаст ресиверы зарегистрированные статически(в манифесте) не принимают неявные (без указания класса) интенты.
Вам надо в методе onResume() зарегистрировать свои ресиверы, а так же передать им интент фильтр с необходимыми действиями

```
private lateinit var chargingReceiver: ChargingReceiver

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    chargingReceiver = ChargingReceiver()
}

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
        registerReceiver(chargingReceiver, intentFilter)
}
```

А в методе onStop() убрать регистрацию

```
override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unregisterReceiver(chargingReceiver)
}
```

Но это не решит все ваши проблемы. Я лишь ответил на вопрос почему ваши ресиверы не реагируют на интенты. Для решения всех остальных задач я рекомендую детальнее ознакомится с использованием сервисов и процессом автозагрузки приложений.

Comment: но у него же указан класс в манифесте который принимает android:name=".RestartReceiver"

Comment: Это в MainActivity, надо добавить?

Comment: Да. Но это не решит все ваши задачи, я обновил ответ

Comment: Да вы правы, это действительно не решает моей проблемы, но все же спасибо за совет, буду углубляться в изучение сервисов

Comment: Это правило распространяется не на все события, есть исключения: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions